# Creating bubble chart with data retrieved from SQL

Tags: .net, teechart

I am creating a TeeChart with the bubble series and I need to populate the series with data from SQL database. I am writing the following code for doing this.

```
DataSet dsPoolPivot = new DataSet();
//Fill the dataset with data from a stored procedure
Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bubble Bubble1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bubble(WebChart1.Chart);
Bubble1.XValues.DataMember = dsPoolPivot.Tables[0].Columns["PaymentAmount"].ToString();
Bubble1.YValues.DataMember = dsPoolPivot.Tables[0].Columns["AllocationAmount"].ToString();
Bubble1.LabelMember = dsPoolPivot.Tables[0].Columns["Product_Desc"].ToString();
Bubble1.DataSource = dsPoolPivot.Tables[0];
```

In addition to this I also have a "ContingencyAmount" parameter in the dataset which I need to set as the size parameter of the bubble chart and also want to set the transparency of the bubbles in the chart.

A similar code works well for the bar chart, but the bubble series is not generated if this code is used.

Any idea as to how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

When you use Bubble Series, parameters you must add are XValues,YValues and Radius if you doesn't assign one of this values the chart isn't drawn correctly. I recommend you, add a column in your dataSource that indicates the radius of Bubble and assign it using a similar code as next:

```
Bubble1.RadiusValues.DataMember= dsPoolPivot.Tables[0].Columns["Radius"].ToString();
```

Could you tell us if previous suggestion help you to solve your problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks Sandra. That help me to work out the issue to some extent